# Why do I need a local database ios

Tags: ios, database

I'm building an app which fetch posts from server. My question is straightforward: My UITableview has a data source. The data source can load data directly from the server when user hit reload. So why do I want a local store like core data?

Comment: It sounds like you probably don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One benefit is that loading from a local data store is much faster than loading from a web service. As such, a common pattern is to cache the most recently retrieved data in a local data store and display that while you're making an asynchronous request for any updates.

One example would be Facebook's apps. When you open them from a completely shutdown state they are populated with previously loaded posts, and when a refresh request completes the UI then refreshes with the new data.

The thing to remember is that with mobile devices network connectivity can be highly variable and/or non-existent. If your app requires connectivity and up to date info at all times, then maybe you don't need a local store? But it does help improve the overall user experience generally speaking.